# Jenkins Job (In Windows environment) not able to access Shared locations

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am trying to schedule a batch in Jenkins (Windows environment) for Windows EXE program (Implemented through .NET).

This program refers to some shared location in the network (viz. \shared network.net\sample path) for the sake of reading from and writing into files.

When I run this program independently out of Jenkins, it works fine, as it considers my login as user who actually has access over shared path.

However, when I run it through Jenkins, there is issue over access.  Through my program logs I checked and found that it uses 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' as user.

I need to make Jenkins job run through particular user's authentication, which will have relevant access over shared path.

Please advise.

Comment: http://antagonisticpleiotropy.blogspot.de/2012/08/running-jenkins-in-windows-with-regular.html

Answer (score 0):

The [Authorize Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin) allows you to run a job as a specific user.

Or, if you are executing from a bat script, you should be able to change the user in your script before running your program.

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

1. Use "net use" to map the network location under the job's session using your credentials.
2. In your Windows slave you can go to services-> Jenkins slave->properties. there under "Log On" section you can specify the user you want the service to run under.

I would definitely go with the first option as it is much more manageable (tomorrow you'll replace your slave and have to do it all over again, instead of just migrating the job and mapping the session again).

Good Luck!