# How to print user defined variable of Windows10 using groovy?

Tags: windows, jenkins, groovy

I am using Windows 10 and have added 'BRANCH_OUTPUT" user-defined variable using 'Edit environment variables for your account'

I've created a little 'groovy script' from 'Jenkins' and trying to print the 'USER DEFINED VARIABLE".  However, script prints 'null' instead of the value

Script

```
println "PATH=" + System.getenv("PATH")
println "TMP=" + System.getenv("TMP")
println "User Var=" + System.getenv("BRANCH_OUTPUT")
```

Script Output

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\printEnvVar
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;

TMP=C:\windows\TEMP

User Var=null
```

Output of 'SET"

```
C:\Users>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
BRANCH_OUTPUT=C:\Temp
```

(1)  It prints System-defined variable
(2)  It prints user-defined variable which 'already exists'

It does NOT print only 'what I added'.  I restarted Jenkins and Windows but nothing worked.  User-defined variable is not getting printed

What should I change in Windows (or)  am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: just to be sure, have you checked that `ALLUSERSPROFILE` isn't set to `C:\ProgramData
BRANCH_OUTPUT=C:\Temp`?

Comment: I see ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData.  Should I change this ?

Comment: I guess you are using `cmd.exe`? Can you please do a `echo %BRANCH_OUTPUT%` to verify that `BRANCH_OUTPUT` is set?

Comment: your jenkins is running on your local windows machine?

Comment: btw: your approach to read the "user defined variable" is the right one. The question is, why it is not set...

Comment: i used cmd.exe and running Jenkins on my local windows machine.  I don't understand 'why the variable is not set' as I am not a Windows guy.  

Output:  C:\>echo %BRANCH_OUTPUT%
C:\Temp

Comment: how did you set your variable?

Comment: could it be that your jenkins runs in another context? when you've started jenkins and then set a variable in another window, jenkins will not get this variable.

Comment: press the windows key and search for "environment". you will get a tool through which you can set user environment variables. these are persistet. restart jenkins. now it should work!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you started jenkins and then tried to set the user defined variable in another shell. This does not work because the shell and jenkins are running in different context.

Press the windows-key and search for "environment". You will find a tool with which you can set user environment variables. These variables are available in all contexts, after the context has been restarted. So you need to restart your jenkins afterwards.

Hope this helps

Comment: It took sometime to understand your answer as i am not a Windows guy.  I already set the variable using 'Edit environment variables for your account', restarted Jenkins and Windows but nothing worked.  I did not set 'env variable' through cmd.exe

Comment: so, you see the variabkes set by the tool in your `cmd.exe` shell? How do you run your jenkins?

Comment: Yes, I am able to see the variable from cmd.exe.  I execute 'Jenkins' as service and it 'Log On As=Local System'.   I added the variable BRANCH_OUTPUT under 'SYSTEM variables' and able to produce the output.  But, my organization does not allow us to manipulate SYSTEM_VARIABLES

Comment: so, did you already restart your machine after addind the variable?

Comment: Yes I already restarted Jenkins and Windows after adding the USER DEFINED VARIABLE

Comment: could it be that the jenkins runs with another user? Try to print the `USERNAME` environment variable. This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465878/jenkins-job-in-windows-environment-not-able-to-access-shared-locations

Answer (score 0):

How is the "user defined variable" defined?  My guess is you defined it in the Windows environment variables applet, as described in the comments for the previous answer.  In your original comment, you mention that it printed the value for a user-defined variable that already exists, but it's not clear what that is.  TMP is displayed as C:\Windows\TEMP, and it is uncommon for TMP to be set to that folder for users - even for a system administrator.  Only the service accounts get that value.  You didn't include TMP in the output of the "set" command, but set typically shows about 50 variables; since only 2 are shown I assume the output was trimmed.

To have user-defined environment variables for your username show up in Jenkins, you would have to run Jenkins as a service using your username.  Open the services applet, select Jenkins service and right-click on Properties, go to the Log On tab, choose the 'This account' radio button and enter your username and password.

If Jenkins has already run under the system's Local Service account (even for a moment), there MIGHT be permissions issues because your account certainly does not have the same permissions and Jenkins MIGHT have created files that it can not access under your account.  You might have to do a clean install, making sure to change the service configuration before you start Jenkins for the first time.  I don't know that this is necessary (I think it is unlikely, unless you have configured security), but I can imagine it is possible.

This is probably not what you want to do for an instance of Jenkins used by others; for that, you would leave Jenkins running as a service under the local system account, and work with your IT/InfoSecurity department to get the variable defined as a system variable as you did working with the people who responded to an earlier answer.  If the variable only needs to be known within Jenkins, you could define it globally within Jenkins (will apply to all jobs: go to "Manage Jenkins", "Configure System", scroll to "Global properties", check "Environement Variables" and add "BUILD_OUTPUT" with the value you want to assign to it) or within the job (will only apply to this job: add a parameter in the job configuration, which is passed to the job as an environment variable.  If you don't want users to be able to change it when they request a build, the "Hidden Parameter Plugin" - not included in Jenkins by default but very easily added - could be used.)

Answer (score 0):

Your Jenkins Service is running with the System User, but you set the Environment Variable for your Windows User. The easiest solution is to change the Jenkins Service to run with the WIndows Account you set the variable for.